# SetFileTime() behaving strangeley

Tags: winapi, mfc

The Windows function SetFileTime() in my company's application is behaving anomalously in 2 ways:

a.) In one case, I'm trying to update the date times (access, create, modify) of a file to "01/01/1980  00:00:00" and the file winds up having its original date times removed.

b.) In another case, the file will have its create and modified date updated to some seemingly random date time like "March ‎17, ‎1817, ‏‎6:26:56 AM".  This one is not easily replicable - the same file can update just fine if I try subsequent times.

Please advise/assist.

In both cases, the update is being done remotely - so the files reside on a different server. The language is MFC C++

Code below:

```
CString csTime;
COleDateTime tCreate, tAccess, tModify;
SYSTEMTIME stCreate, stAccess, stModify;
FILETIME ftCreate, ftAccess, ftModify;


csTime = pMeta->Get( _T("CreateTime") );
    if ( !csTime.IsEmpty() )
tCreate.ParseDateTime( csTime, 0UL, 1033 );
else
    tCreate = COleDateTime::GetCurrentTime();

tCreate.GetAsSystemTime( stCreate );
BOOL stBool = SystemTimeToFileTime( &stCreate, &ftCreate );

csTime = pMeta->Get( _T("ModifyTime") );
if ( !csTime.IsEmpty() )
    tModify.ParseDateTime( csTime, 0UL, 1033 );
else
    tModify = COleDateTime::GetCurrentTime();

tModify.GetAsSystemTime( stModify );
BOOL stBool2 = SystemTimeToFileTime( &stModify, &ftModify );

csTime = pMeta->Get( _T("AccessTime") );
if ( !csTime.IsEmpty() )
    tAccess.ParseDateTime( csTime, 0UL, 1033 );
else
    tAccess = COleDateTime::GetCurrentTime();

    tAccess.GetAsSystemTime( stAccess );
    BOOL stBool3 = SystemTimeToFileTime( &stAccess, &ftAccess );


// write MAC times
HANDLE hTarget = CreateFile( csTest, GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL );
BOOL winAPI = SetFileTime( hTarget, &ftCreate, &ftAccess, &ftModify );
CloseHandle( hTarget );
```

Comment: What do the input strings look like? Are they in local time or UTC? `SetFileTime()` expects UTC. Where is your error handling?

Comment: It looks like you've asked the question too early. You need to debug this before asking. You'll have no problem solving this if you do some debugging. The complete absence of error checking is obviously a big problem.

Comment: Remy - I will check the input strings.  I do think it is UTC but I will confirm.  Thank you.
David and Remy - thank you for your comments; the program is not crashing - hovering over the BOOL variables like stBool and winAPI shows the function running successfully as the values are 1.  So the functions run but it's not returning the results expected. Thank you.